# How to extend a data.table using Reference Classes?

Tags: r, data.table, reference-class

### Problem:

I wish to create a Reference Class that extends a `data.table`.

The motivation being

1. Want a `data.table` with custom methods and mutable fields
2. Still want all existing syntax (such as indexing, subset, merge etc) to work as expected

Problem is I have so far failed.

### Attempts:

I tried:

```
MyDataTable <- setRefClass("MyDataTable",
    methods = list(
        clearCell = function(i, j) {        # A trivial custom method - sets a cell to NA
            .self[i, (j) := NA]
        }
    ),
    contains = "data.table"
)

MyDataTable(a = 1:26, b = letters)$clearCell(1, 1)
```

But got the error:

```
Error in envRefSetField(.Object, field, classDef, selfEnv, elements[[field]]) : 
  ‘a’ is not a field in class “MyDataTable”
```

However, I was expecting something like:

```
     a b
 1: NA a
 2:  2 b
 3:  3 c
 4:  4 d
 5:  5 e
 6:  ... etc etc
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: I'm curious about the motivation - can please give an example problem?

Comment: @eddi - many examples of why one might want to extend the capabilities of a `data.table`. For instance, consider a `data.table` that is an abstraction of a database table. That is, I can write to the database table simply via `MyTable[id == 4, field := "a"]` *and* also have the in-memory table within my R session updated. For this to work, such an extended `data.table` would need to keep track of additional variables such as (database connection, name of database table it is linked to etc.) which would be best stored as reference class fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing your reference class object correctly. I don't know how `contains` is supposed to work, but a simple field works:

```
MyDataTable <- setRefClass("MyDataTable",
                   fields  = list(.dt = 'data.table'),
                   methods = list(initialize = function(...){
                                    .self$.dt <- data.table(...)
                                  },
                                  clearCell  = function(i, j){
                                    .self$.dt[i, (j) := NA]
                                  },
                                  bracket    = function(...){
                                    .self$.dt[...]
                                  }
                                  ))

MyDataTable(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])$clearCell(1,1)
#    a b
#1: NA a
#2:  2 b
#3:  3 c
#4:  4 d
#5:  5 e

MyDataTable(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])$bracket(b == 'c', a := 10)
#    a b
#1:  1 a
#2:  2 b
#3: 10 c
#4:  4 d
#5:  5 e
```

Comment: Thanks @eddi, but my second request in the question was: `still want all existing syntax (such as indexing, subset, merge etc) to work as expected`. However, with your setup, using the usual indexing like `MyDataTable(a = 1:5)[, a := a + 1]` fails.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that. You could add a different function that would call `[.data.table` though - see edit.